# How I can return multiple values of different data types from a method?

Tags: java

I have following method,

```
public Response process(Applicant appl)
{

    String responseString;
    String requestString;
    requestString = createRequestString(appl);
    responseString = sendRequest(requestString);
    Response response = parseResponse(responseString);
    return response;
}
```

Here I want to return both responseString  and response, one is of type String and other is an object of class Response. How can I do this?

Comment: Why not have the ˋResponseˋ  class also keep hold of ˋresponseStringˋ? It looks like the obvious container for that.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830949/how-to-return-an-integer-or-int-and-a-list-from-a-method-in-java

Comment: Same question as here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439782/overload-with-different-return-type-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot.

You can only return the type you mentioned in method signature.

What you can do is,

Create a field in `Response` class called `responseString` and add `setters` and `getters`.

```
public Response process(Applicant appl)
{

    String responseString;
    String requestString;
    requestString = createRequestString(appl);
    responseString = sendRequest(requestString);
    Response response = parseResponse(responseString);
    response.setResponseString(responseString);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: In the general case this solution will fail as you usually cannot change the `Response` class. E.g. if it is a JSONObject or similar. This may be good for the OP but not a good solution for most cases.

Comment: @allprog Yes it is purely depends..If you are able to change The response object this is a solution.OP not mentioned that I cannot change the response object.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom type, which holds both of the values.

```
public class ResponseObject {
    private String responseString;

    private Response response;

    //accessors
}
```

and then return an instance of that class as a result.

Answer (score 3):

you can return array of objects as follows:

```
public Object[] process(Applicant appl)
{
...
```

but you need to keep track of index of the inserted objects (String, Response)

Another way, you can return `Map<String, Object>` having keys representing the values.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a wrapper class for that. Unlike some other languages the Java language doesn't support tuple return values with automatic unpacking. Simply create a data class like this:

```
class ResponseData {
    public final String responseString;
    public final Response response;

    public ResponseData(String responseString, Response response) {
        this.responseString = responseString;
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both the objects are separate entities, the prefered way to do this is via [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance):

```
    String responseString;
    String requestString;
    requestString = createRequestString(appl);
    responseString = sendRequest(requestString);
    Response response = parseResponse(responseString);

    return new compositObj(response, responseString);




  class compositObj{
      Response res;
      String resString;
      compositObj(Response r, String s){
        res = r;
        resString = s;
    }
    //getters setters if needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java methods are determined by its signatures. There can only be existed one unique signature in a scope.

> **Method Signature**: Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the method signature—the method's name and the parameter
>   types.

As suggested in the description return types are not in signature, so it is impossible to have two methods that differs only by return types.

However, there is several ways to return different object types.

**Object type**

Return `Object` type since all classes are type of `Object`, then cast it to proper type.

```
public Object process(Applicant appl);
```

**Inheritance**

Define a base class and derive`Response` and `ResponseString` from base

```
class ResponseBase
{

}
```

and derive your classes

```
class Response extends ResponseBase{...}
class ResponseString ResponseBase{...}
```

and return base class from your method

public ResponseBase process(Applicant appl);

**Composition**

Wrap your `Response` and `ResponseString` to a wrapper class and return it.

```
class ResponseWrapper
{
    Response response;
    ResponseString responseString;
     //getter setters

}
```

and return `ResponseWrapper` from your method

```
public ResponseWrapper process(Applicant appl);
```

**See also**

[Design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707195/892994)

[Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

option 1.
you can return your CustomeResponse.

```
public class CustomResponse {

   private String responseString;
   private Response response;

   public void setResponseString(String responseString){
     this.responseString = responseString;
   }
   public String getResponseString(){
     return this.responseString;
   }

   public void setResponse(Response response){
     this.response = response;
   }
   public Response getResponse(){
     return this.response;
   }
}
```

option 2. 
you can pass responseString as parameter. as non primitive datatypes passed as argument has the reference of the variable so when you will set responseString, your variable value will be updated.

```
public Response process(Applicant appl,String responseString)
{
    String requestString;
    requestString = createRequestString(appl);
    responseString = sendRequest(requestString);
    Response response = parseResponse(responseString);
    return response;
}
```