# Always the same random numbers in HashSet

Tags: java, random, hashset

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Random rand;
    private HashSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>> set;

    public MyClass()
    {
       rand = new Random(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));
       set = new HashSet<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();
    }


    public void doSomething(int len)
    {   
        set.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int index = rand.nextInt(len - 1) + 1;

            int min = 1 - index;
            int max = len - index - 1;
            int j = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

            if (j != 0)
            {   
               set.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(index, j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Pair` is a custom class where I can store two integers. The problem is that every time I call `doSomething()` the `HashSet` contains always the same values.

How is it possible? How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT:**

this is my Pair: https://stackoverflow.com/a/677248/1395740

Comment: What are the the `equals` and `hashCode` methods on your `Pair` class?

Comment: did you create new MyClass instance , or use the old one ?

Comment: @Gladiator I use only one instance of MyClass, so the old one...

Comment: why not just using new Random()

Comment: What int value are you passing as argument to the doSomething() call?

Comment: Can you show us the code of Pair (if is not just 2 values + getters/setters)?

Comment: @NickDK Always the same, it represents the length of an array

Comment: @Nick I tried your code with a dummy implementation for Pair and it works : my pairs are different. Are you sure that you don't have a problem in the code you use to check the values?

Comment: you could try to do `rand = new Random(i);` inside your for loop and the 2 calls could just be `my_random_value = rand.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

> An instance of this class is used to generate a stream of
>   pseudorandom numbers. The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified
>   using a linear congruential formula. (See Donald Knuth, The Art of
>   Computer Programming, Volume 3, Section 3.2.1.)
>
> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the
>   same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and
>   return identical sequences of numbers.

Comment: That's what I thought about but the seed is itself random (`new Random(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()))`). I looked at the implementation of Random and `new Random()` uses `System.nanotime()`.

Answer (score 0):

Math.random returns a double and Random receives a long as its seed. So probably you are getting 0 as the seed everytime. Try to change to System.getNanoTime() just for a test and see what happens.

Comment: That is not what the OP is doing, the OP uses `Double.doubleToLongBits`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your code, when run it with 5 as len parameter it's result this:
[(4, -2), (4, -1), (4, -3), (2, -1), (3, -1), (3, -2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3)]
[(4, -2), (3, -1), (4, -1), (4, -3), (3, -2), (2, -1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3)]

if you trace your code, it's not same pair, every time doSomething method generate new random numbers, but in loop , all numbers that lead j !=0 will ignored, so you will have that pairs,

your problem in this code

```
    int index = rand.nextInt(len - 1) + 1;
    int min = 1 - index;
    int max = len - index - 1;
    int j = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

    if (j != 0)
    {   
       set.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(index, j));
    }
```

i mean this code leads to got same number regardless what random number be.

Comment: So the solution to fix the problem is...?

Comment: this code will generate all probabilities of two integers (pair) where it's less than len (method parameter), so every time you will have same pair with deference order ,  solution will be regarding to your business ,