# How to make a Java Hashmap with three parameters

Tags: java, list, hash, parameters, hashmap

How do I use Hashmap with 3 parameters with string, string, int.  The first string is a location, the second string is a different location, and the int represents the time from one to the other.

If I make a key posistion1, position3, int it will tell me how much time between position1 and position3.

There is 100 locations and I need to specify the time between all locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use some `Pair` class (that simply stores two parameters and implements `hashCode` and `equals` correctly) as the key of your HashMap. There is an implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677248/554281) or you can write your own, more specific to your purpose (with more sensible variable and method names).

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap maps one variable to one other variable. You want to use two variables as a key,  so you can make a simple Coordinates class.

```
class Coordinates {
    final int x;
    final int y;
    public Coordinates(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Coordinates other = (Coordinates) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<"+x+","+"y"+">";
    }
}
```

In this code, the `hashCode` and `equals`methods have been generated by Eclipse. All you need to know is that `hashCode` generates a number which Map uses as identifier for your coordinate and that `equals` checks if two Coordinates point to the same place.

You can then use a `Map<Coordinates,String>` for your map. To add something you use:

```
yourMap.add(new Coordinates(2,3), "A String")
```

To retrieve something you use

```
yourMap.get(new Coordinates(2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to create a map of position1, position2 that holds some attribute of the pair in a map. First, you need to be sure that the map doesn't get too large. 10,000 entries isn't huge for small instances.

Create a PositionPair class that overrides equals() (and hashCode(), because they two need to agree.) You could use the class as the key in a Map, which answers your question.

Or you could simply add the attribute to the class and store instances in a List. If you want to get fancy, don't calculate the time until it is requested the first time, then save it before returning it.