# Does Java SE 8 have Pairs or Tuples?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I am playing around with lazy functional operations in Java SE 8, and I want to `map` an index `i` to a pair / tuple `(i, value[i])`, then `filter` based on the second `value[i]` element, and finally output just the indices.

Must I still suffer this: [What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair<L,R> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java) in the bold new era of lambdas and streams?

**Update:** I presented a rather simplified example, which has a neat solution offered by @dkatzel in one of the answers below. However, it does *not* generalize. Therefore, let me add a more general example:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean [][] directed_acyclic_graph = new boolean[][]{
        {false,  true, false,  true, false,  true},
        {false, false, false,  true, false,  true},
        {false, false, false,  true, false,  true},
        {false, false, false, false, false,  true},
        {false, false, false, false, false,  true},
        {false, false, false, false, false, false}
    };

    System.out.println(
        IntStream.range(0, directed_acyclic_graph.length)
        .parallel()
        .mapToLong(i -> IntStream.range(0, directed_acyclic_graph[i].length)
            .filter(j -> directed_acyclic_graph[j][i])
            .count()
        )
        .filter(n -> n == 0)
        .collect(() -> new ArrayList<Long>(), (c, e) -> c.add(e), (c1, c2) -> c1.addAll(c2))
    );
  }

}
```

This gives **incorrect** output of `[0, 0, 0]` which corresponds to the *counts* for the three columns that are all `false`. What I need are the *indices* of these three columns. The correct output should be `[0, 2, 4]`. How can I get this result?

Comment: There’s already [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html) for years… But anyway, instead of mapping `i` to `(i, value[i])` just for filtering by `value[i]` and mapping back to `i`: *why not just filter by `value[i]` in the first place, without the mapping?*

Comment: @Holger I need to know which indices of an array contain values that match a criteria. I can't do it without preserving `i` in the stream. I also need `value[i]` for the criteria. That's why I need `(i, value[i])`

Comment: @necromancer Does the technique in [dkatzel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24330226/1441122) help?

Comment: @StuartMarks yes, that's a nice technique; I commented on it. It doesn't generalize because I am actually generating values on the fly by a map operation on an outer stream. I thought I'd be helpful by presenting a simplified use case, and sure enough dkatzel solved it well :) But I am still stuck.  I have a 2-d matrix representing a directed graph, and I want to find which vertices have zero incoming edges.

Comment: @necromancer Right, it only works if it's cheap to get to the value from the index, such as an array, a random access collection, or an inexpensive function. I guess the problem is that you wanted to present a simplified use case, but it was oversimplified and thus succumbed to a special case.

Comment: @necromancer I edited the last paragraph a bit to clarify the question I think you're asking. Is it right? Also, is this a question about a *directed* (not acyclic) graph? (Not that it matters much.) Finally, should the desired output be `[0, 2, 4]`?

Comment: @StuartMarks thanks for the edits. Yes, it is about a directed graph, and the desired output should indeed be [0, 2, 4] (I'm such a scatterbrain today). I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: I believe that the right solution to fix this is to have a future Java release support tuples as a return type (as a special case of Object) and have lambda expressions be able to use such a tuple directly for its parameters.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This answer is in response to the original question, *Does Java SE 8 have Pairs or Tuples?* (And implicitly, if not, why not?) The OP has updated the question with a more complete example, but it seems like it can be solved without using any kind of Pair structure. [Note from OP: here is [the other correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328679/does-java-se-8-have-pairs-or-tuples/24339157#24339157).]

---

The short answer is no. You either have to roll your own or bring in one of the several libraries that implements it.

Having a `Pair` class in Java SE was proposed and rejected at least once. See [this discussion thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-March/003973.html) on one of the OpenJDK mailing lists. The tradeoffs are not obvious. On the one hand, there are many Pair implementations in other libraries and in application code. That demonstrates a need, and adding such a class to Java SE will increase reuse and sharing. On the other hand, having a Pair class adds to the temptation of creating complicated data structures out of Pairs and collections without creating the necessary types and abstractions. (That's a paraphrase of [Kevin Bourillion's message](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-March/003995.html) from that thread.)

I recommend everybody read that entire email thread. It's remarkably insightful and has no flamage. It's quite convincing. When it started I thought, "Yeah, there should be a Pair class in Java SE" but by the time the thread reached its end I had changed my mind.

Note however that JavaFX has the [javafx.util.Pair](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) class. JavaFX's APIs evolved separately from the Java SE APIs.

As one can see from the linked question [What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java) there is quite a large design space surrounding what is apparently such a simple API. Should the objects be immutable? Should they be serializable? Should they be comparable? Should the class be final or not? Should the two elements be ordered? Should it be an interface or a class? Why stop at pairs? Why not triples, quads, or N-tuples?

And of course there is the inevitable naming bikeshed for the elements:

- (a, b)
- (first, second)
- (left, right)
- (car, cdr)
- (foo, bar)
- etc.

One big issue that has hardly been mentioned is the relationship of Pairs to primitives. If you have an `(int x, int y)` datum that represents a point in 2D space, representing this as `Pair<Integer, Integer>` consumes **three objects** instead of two 32-bit words. Furthermore, these objects must reside on the heap and will incur GC overhead.

It would seem clear that, like Streams, it would be essential for there to be primitive specializations for Pairs. Do we want to see:

```
Pair
ObjIntPair
ObjLongPair
ObjDoublePair
IntObjPair
IntIntPair
IntLongPair
IntDoublePair
LongObjPair
LongIntPair
LongLongPair
LongDoublePair
DoubleObjPair
DoubleIntPair
DoubleLongPair
DoubleDoublePair
```

Even an `IntIntPair` would still require one object on the heap.

These are, of course, reminiscent of the proliferation of functional interfaces in the `java.util.function` package in Java SE 8. If you don't want a bloated API, which ones would you leave out? You could also argue that this isn't enough, and that specializations for, say, `Boolean` should be added as well.

My feeling is that if Java had added a Pair class long ago, it would have been simple, or even simplistic, and it wouldn't have satisfied many of the use cases we are envisioning now. Consider that if Pair had been added in the JDK 1.0 time frame, it probably would have been mutable! (Look at java.util.Date.) Would people have been happy with that? My guess is that if there were a Pair class in Java, it would be kinda-sort-not-really-useful and everybody will still be rolling their own to satisfy their needs, there would be various Pair and Tuple implementations in external libraries, and people would still be arguing/discussing about how to fix Java's Pair class. In other words, kind of in the same place we're at today.

Meanwhile, some work is going on to address the fundamental issue, which is better support in the JVM (and eventually the Java language) for *value types*. See this [State of the Values](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html) document. This is preliminary, speculative work, and it covers only issues from the JVM perspective, but it already has a fair amount of thought behind it. Of course there are no guarantees that this will get into Java 9, or ever get in anywhere, but it does show the current direction of thinking on this topic.

Comment: regarding primitive specializations, would overloaded factory methods instead of constructors ameliorate the issue: `Pair.valueOf(...)`? tangent: why did Java not make the constructor for `Integer` private? I think having `Integer.valueOf` as the only way to access `Integer` objects?

Comment: @necromancer Factory methods with primitives don't help for `Pair<T,U>`. Since generics must be of reference type. Any primitives will be boxed when they're stored. To store primitives you really need a different class.

Comment: @necromancer And yes in retrospect the boxed primitive constructors shouldn't have been public, and `valueOf` should have been the only way to get a boxed instance. But those have been in there since Java 1.0 and probably aren't worth trying to change at this point.

Comment: Thank you for that insight. I hope the State of the Values proposal moves forward; it's about time! (also therein are references to James Gosling on the topic of Efficient Classes).

Comment: Obviously, there should be only *one* public `Pair` or `Tuple` class with a factory method creating necessary specialization classes (with optimized storage) transparently in the background. In the end, lambdas do exactly that: they may capture an arbitrary number of variables of arbitrary type. And now image a language support allowing to create the appropriate tuple class at runtime triggered by an `invokedynamic` instruction…

Comment: @Holger Something like that might work if one were retrofitting value types onto the existing JVM, but the Value Types proposal (now ["Project Valhalla"](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2014-June/003445.html)) is much more radical. In particular, its value types would not necessarily be heap-allocated. Also, unlike objects today, and like primitives today, values would have no identity.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: That wouldn’t interfere as the type I described could be the “boxed” type for such a value type. With an `invokedynamic` based factory similar to the lambda creation such later-on retrofitting would be no problem. By the way, lambdas have no identity as well. As explicitly stated, the identity you might perceive today is an artifact of the current implementation.

Comment: > Why stop at pairs? Why not triples, quads, or N-tuples?

Is this supposed to be an argument against tuples? Because N-tuples would be really useful.

Comment: We have `Map.Entry` which can always be used when `Pair` is needed.  As this rarely happen it indicates that the facility is not craved enough to warrant using an existing class for this.

Comment: The fact that Pair's presence encourages bad programmer behavior does not mean its absence encourages better programmer behavior: rather than return Pair<A, B>, developers turn to Object[], to List<Object>, to Map.Entry<A, B>, to their own ill-considered implementation, or to one of many other nonstandard implementations. All of those are worse than a standardized Tuple library, which is why other well-designed languages include tuple libraries.

Comment: Both Scala and Spark (even the Java Spark API), show how powerful the concept of a Pair or Tuple can be. The point is not to have that as a simplistic abstraction of your data needs, but the Stream / RDD api's on top of it that get generalized based on those Pairs, particularly things like groupBy reduceBy. `RDD<Pair<K,V>>` --> `groupByKey` --> `RDD<Pair<K,List<V>>`. Something that can be mimicked in Java 8 but at a great implementation cost. All our Java 8 Streams are missing essential K/V processing.

Comment: @StuartMarks, re "discussing about how to fix Java"; But that's a given. should Java stop shipping anything then?

Answer (score 63):

You can have a look on these built-in classes :

- [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)
- [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html)

Comment: This is the correct answer, as far as built-in functionality for pairs. Note that `SimpleImmutableEntry` only guarantees that the references stored in the `Entry` don't change, not that the fields of the linked `key` and `value` objects (or those of objects they link to) don't change.

Answer (score 30):

Sadly, Java 8 did not introduce pairs or tuples. You can always use [org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/package-summary.html) of course (which personally I do use in combination with Java 8) or you can create your own wrappers. Or use Maps. Or stuff like that, as is explained in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/156685/2382246) to that question you linked to.

---

**UPDATE:** JDK 14 introduced [record classes](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) as a preview feature, JDK 16 introduced them as a [standard language feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). These aren't tuples, but can be used to save many of the same problems. In your specific example from above, that could look something like this:

```java
public class Jdk14Example {
    record CountForIndex(int index, long count) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean [][] directed_acyclic_graph = new boolean[][]{
                {false,  true, false,  true, false,  true},
                {false, false, false,  true, false,  true},
                {false, false, false,  true, false,  true},
                {false, false, false, false, false,  true},
                {false, false, false, false, false,  true},
                {false, false, false, false, false, false}
        };

        System.out.println(
                IntStream.range(0, directed_acyclic_graph.length)
                        .parallel()
                        .mapToObj(i -> {
                            long count = IntStream.range(0, directed_acyclic_graph[i].length)
                                            .filter(j -> directed_acyclic_graph[j][i])
                                            .count();
                            return new CountForIndex(i, count);
                        }
                        )
                        .filter(n -> n.count == 0)
                        .collect(() -> new ArrayList<CountForIndex>(), (c, e) -> c.add(e), (c1, c2) -> c1.addAll(c2))
        );
    }
}
```

When compiled and run with [JDK 14](http://jdk.java.net/14/) using the `--enable-preview` flag or [JDK 16](http://jdk.java.net/16/) or later, you get the following result:

```
[CountForIndex[index=0, count=0], CountForIndex[index=2, count=0], CountForIndex[index=4, count=0]]
```

Comment: Actually one of the answers by @StuartMarks allowed me to solve it without tuples, but since it doesn't seem to generalize I probably will need it eventually.

Comment: @necromancer Yes, it is a very good answer. The apache library can still come in handy at times but it all comes down to Javas language design. Basically, tuples would have to be primitives (or similar) to work as they do in other languages.

Comment: In case you didn't notice it, the answer included this extremely informative link: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html about the need for and the prospects for such primitives including tuples.

Answer (score 28):

Since Java 9, you can create instances of `Map.Entry` easier than before:

```
Entry<Integer, String> pair = Map.entry(1, "a");
```

[`Map.entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) returns an unmodifiable `Entry` and forbids nulls.

Answer (score 19):

It appears that the full example can be solved without the use of any kind of Pair structure. The key is to filter on the column indexes, with the predicate checking the entire column, instead of mapping the column indexes to the number of `false` entries in that column.

The code that does this is here:

```
    System.out.println(
        IntStream.range(0, acyclic_graph.length)
            .filter(i -> IntStream.range(0, acyclic_graph.length)
                                  .noneMatch(j -> acyclic_graph[j][i]))
            .boxed()
            .collect(toList()));
```

This results in output of `[0, 2, 4]` which is I think the correct result requested by the OP.

Also note the `boxed()` operation that boxes the `int` values into `Integer` objects. This enables one to use the pre-existing `toList()` collector instead having to write out collector functions that do the boxing themselves.

Comment: +1 ace up your sleeve :) This still doesn't generalize, right? That was the more substantial aspect of the question because I expect to face other situations where a scheme such as this won't work (for example columns with no more than 3 values `true`). Accordingly, I will accept your other answer as correct, but also point to this one! Thanks very much :)

Comment: This is correct but accepting the other answer by the same user. (see comments above and elsewhere.)

Comment: @necromancer Right, this technique isn't fully general in the cases where you want the index, but the data element can't be retrieved or computed using the index. (At least not easily.) For example, consider a problem where you're reading lines of text from a network connection, and you want to find the line number of the Nth line that matches some pattern. The easiest way is to map each line into a Pair or some composite data structure to number the lines. There's probably a hacky, side-effecty way to do this without a new data structure though.

Comment: @StuartMarks, A pair is <T, U>. a triple <T, U, V>. etc. Your example is a list, not a pair.

Answer (score 8):

**Vavr (formerly called Javaslang)** (http://www.vavr.io) provides tuples (til size of 8) as well. Here is the javadoc: https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.0/io/vavr/Tuple.html.

This is a simple example:

```
Tuple2<Integer, String> entry = Tuple.of(1, "A");

Integer key = entry._1;
String value = entry._2;
```

Why JDK itself did not come with a simple kind of tuples til now is a mystery to me. Writing wrapper classes seems to be an every day business.

Comment: Some versions of vavr used sneaky throws under the hood.  Be careful not to use those.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

`Map.Entry` can be used as a `Pair`.

Unfortunately it does not help with Java 8 streams as the problem is that even though lambdas can take multiple arguments, the Java language only allows for returning a single value (object or primitive type).  This implies that whenever you have a stream you end up with being passed a single object from the previous operation.  This is a lack in the Java language, because if multiple return values was supported AND streams supported them we could have much nicer non-trivial tasks done by streams.

Until then, there is only little use.

EDIT 2021-05-10: Java 16 brought records which is a very nice solution to this and other issues.  A very strong reason to target Java 17 LTS coming soon

Answer (score 6):

Since you only care about the indexes, you don't need to map to tuples at all.  Why not just write a filter that uses the looks up elements in your array?

```
     int[] value =  ...


IntStream.range(0, value.length)
            .filter(i -> value[i] > 30)  //or whatever filter you want
            .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Comment: +1 for great, practical solution. However, I am not sure if it generalizes to my situation where I am generating the values on the fly. I posed my question as an array to offer a simple case to think about and you did come up with an excellent solution.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse Collections has `Pair` and all combinations of primitive/object Pairs (for all eight primitives).

The [`Tuples`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/eclipse-collections/src/main/java/org/eclipse/collections/impl/tuple/Tuples.java) factory can create instances of `Pair`, and the [`PrimitiveTuples`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/blob/master/eclipse-collections/src/main/java/org/eclipse/collections/impl/tuple/primitive/PrimitiveTuples.java) factory can be used to create all combinations of primitive/object pairs.

We added these before Java 8 was released.  They were useful to implement key/value Iterators for our primitive maps, which we also support in all primitive/object combinations.

If you're willing to add the extra library overhead, you can use Stuart's accepted solution and collect the results into a primitive `IntList` to avoid boxing.  We added new methods in [Eclipse Collections 9.0](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/releases/tag/9.0.0) to allow for `Int/Long/Double` collections to be created from `Int/Long/Double` Streams.

```
IntList list = IntLists.mutable.withAll(intStream);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

Many third party libraries support tuples. For example jOOλ, supports [tuples](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/lambda/tuple/Tuple.html) from degree `0` to `16`, e.g.:

```java
// Assuming this static import
import static org.jooq.lambda.tuple.Tuple.*;

// Write:
var t = tuple(1, "a", 2L);
Integer i = t.v1;
String s = t.v2;
Long l = t.v3;
```

Other libraries that have tuples too, e.g.:

- [Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/index.html?reactor/util/function/Tuples.html)
- [Javatuples](https://www.javatuples.org/)
- [Apache Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/tuple/Tuple4.html)
- [Vavr](https://docs.vavr.io/#_tuples)