# Can Bifunction be used to replace a Tuple in Java 8?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

While doing some functional programming in Java 8, I needed a tuple like in any functional programming languages, but then I figured out that  the language designer might be solving the need for Tuple by making the [`Bifunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).

If you need a function that's taking 2 parameters you have to use Bifunction not Function, but I could not find any Documentation about this, is Java 8 really missing Tuples, or Bifunction can replace it's use?

**Edit 1:**

this question not as "Does Java SE 8 have Pairs or Tuples?" as the majority here is Bifunction which is not mentioned in the other question, I think question title now is more descriptive.

Comment: yes thanks for correcting me (y)

Comment: There are good reasons for not including tuples (and pair). If you were considering using `Function<Pair<T,U>, R>` then yes, `BiFunction<T,U,R>` is what you should use. There is no explicit documentation telling you this. Another approach would be to create a tuple like class yourself (but with more sensible accessor methods than `left()` and `right()`), and use that.

Comment: An extensive answer why there are no tuples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24336841/875083

Comment: Also give this a read https://dzone.com/articles/whats-wrong-java-8-part-v

Comment: What I really love about Java is that people would write long articles and white papers explaining why you don't need something :-) Fortunately there are third-party libraries that implement tuples and other convenient features. I use [Javaslang](http://javaslang.com/)

Comment: for comments with answers and article they are all good answers but they are not providing Bifunction instead of Tuble except in dzone link "(int x, int y) -> x * y", @S.D. I'm going to check it and I'm believing there are other  third-party libraries provides the same, but just wanted to know the reason why not in JDK ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `BiFunction` since it doesn't really match the semantics of what you are trying to do. I also don't see how you would propose to get two different values out of a `BiFunction` since it only returns one element of one type.

[Apache Commons-Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang) has a [tuple package](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/package-summary.html) package that will do.

But otherwise I'd suggest creating a class with two named fields so that the semantics of the pairing are captured.

```
class UserName {
    private String userName, phoneNumber;
}
```

communicates intent in the variable names and it is different from

```
class UserPassword {
    private String userName, password;
}
```

If you are using these in a limited scope (ie only within a class or package) I wouldn't bother with getters and setters.

Otherwise, you are trying to abstract over the shape of the data and not the type or semantics of the class which is very un-idiomatic in Java. For more on the topic see [answer posted as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328679/does-java-se-8-have-pairs-or-tuples/24336841#24336841).