# Is there anyway to have a linked list of dimension? like (x, y)?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to see if I could have a java linked list of dimensions x, y ( not using hash map and not having x and y as two separate integers)
I'm trying to store each square of a grid in a linked list for example 
(0, 1) (0, 2) ..

Comment: Linked List of Linked Lists? It's possible, yes ...

Comment: Java's missing Tuple...

Comment: You need to define a class to contain the x and y values of each dimension, let's call it `Dimension`, and then declare a `List<Dimension>`.

Comment: You probably don't want to be storing anything in an actual LinkedList.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Does Java SE 8 have Pairs or Tuples?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24328679/230513)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can store pairs of `x, y` in a `LinkedList<Point>` as follow:

```
List<Point> pointList = new LinkedList<>();
pointList.add(new Point(0, 1));
pointList.add(new Point(0, 2));
```

Where `Point` is pre-defined in `java.awt` package. It has some useful methods such as `public void move(int x, int y)` or `public void translate(int x, int y)` which I think is useful for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add some class for a dimension:

```
public class Dimension {
    private Integer x, y;

    public Dimension(Integer x, Integer y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // getters/setters/equals/hashCode
}
```

Thus you can save dimensions into LinkedList using objects of this class:

```
List<Dimension> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(new Dimension(0, 1));
list.add(new Dimension(1, 2));
```

Comment: Why is `x` and `y` of type `Integer`, and not `int`?

Comment: FYI: `Dimension` is typically used to represent size - especially considering there's already a `Dimension` class in the API

Comment: Thank you! how about if I want to use contains?

Comment: @Ahmed it should work if you will add correct equals() impl