# How to group a list of objects by an attribute and then iterate the results using (Key, Value) pair?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to Group a list of objects by an attribute and then iterate the results using (Key, Value) pair.

I have found the way in Java 8 to group the list of objects with an attribute as follows

```
// filteredPageLog has the filtered results from PageLog entity.

Map<String, List<PageLog>> results = 
filteredPageLog.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getSessionId()));
```

But the results will have only entry sets(has values inside entrySet attribute). The keySet and valueSet will be having null values. I want to iterate something like

```
results.forEach((key,value) -> {
//logic
});
```

Comment: done in your desired way: `results.forEach((key,value) -> {
//logic
});`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
results.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
     var key = entry.getKey();
     var value = entry.getValue();
//logic
});
```

Comment: getting null pointer exception on this line "results.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {" @talex

Comment: @MohammedShirhaan this mean `results` is null.

Comment: The entrySet has values when I debug. @talex

Comment: @What is `null` then?

Comment: for (Map.Entry<String, List<PageLog>> entry : results.entrySet())
        {
            String sessionId = entry.getKey();
            List<PageLog> pageLogs = entry.getValue();
            //logic
           
        } // this worked

Answer (score 2):

Dummy `map`:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap() {{
             put("1","20");
             put("2","30");
           }};
```

---

**You can do it in two ways:**

**1.** `Map<K, V>.forEach()` expects a `BiConsumer<? super K,? super V>` as
    argument, and the signature of the `BiConsumer<T, U>` abstract
    method is `accept(T t, U u)`.

```
map.forEach((keys,values) -> { String k = keys ;
                               String v= values;
                                //logic goes here
                              });
```

---

**2.** `Map<K, V>.entrySet().forEach()` expects a `Consumer<? super T>` as
        argument, and the signature of the `Consumer<T>` abstract
        method is `accept(T t)`.

```
map.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> { String k = entry.getKey();
                                    String v= entry.getValue();
                                    //logic goes here
                                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no tuples in Java. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328679/does-java-se-8-have-pairs-or-tuples/24329071) you can find more detailed explanation. You can iterate over keys, values or entries, but not tuples.

Comment: There is no tuples means?

Comment: Means there is no syntactic sugar like in Scala, for example, see https://www.alexecollins.com/java-tuples. In Java you can't write (key, value) instead of entry. Only as a lambda to overloaded method, which receives suitable functional interface.

Comment: cant write `can't write (key, value) instead of entry` you sure?

Comment: I forgot about map.forEach(BiConsumer<? super K,? super V>), your answer is perfect. So, in this case lambda looks like two element tuple )

Comment: exactly! don't worry i was checking your concept. :)