# ExecutorService - Unable to stop Thread from ServletContextListener when the context is destroyed

Tags: java, multithreading

I am starting a `Thread` from `ServletContextListener` when the context is initialized and trying to stop it when the context is destroyed. The class is:

```
public enum BlinkLedTask {

    INSTANCE;

    private Logger logger = RpiLogger.getLogger(getClass());

    private Task task;
    private ExecutorService service;

    private BlinkLedTask() {

    }

    public void run(String[] frequency) {
        stop();

        task = new Task(frequency);
        service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(RpiThreadFactory.INSTANCE);
        service.execute(task);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if(Objects.isNull(task) || Objects.isNull(service)) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            task.terminate();
            service.shutdownNow();
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            logger.error(cause.getMessage(), cause);
        }       
    }

    private static class Task implements Runnable {

        private volatile boolean running = true;
        private String[] frequency;
        private volatile Logger logger = RpiLogger.getLogger(getClass());

        private Task(String[] frequency) {
            this.frequency = frequency;
        }       

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(running && !Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    resetLed();
                    blinkLed();
                } catch (Throwable cause) {
                    logger.error(cause.getMessage(), cause);
                    running = false;

                    try {
                        resetLed();             
                    } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        private void resetLed() throws Exception {
            executeScript(Script.BLINK_LED_RESET);      
        }

        private void blinkLed() throws Exception {
            executeScript(Script.BLINK_LED, new String[]{frequency[0], frequency[1], frequency[2]});        
        }

        private void executeScript(Script script, String... args) {
            ScriptExecutor scriptExecutor = new ScriptExecutor(ScriptExecutor.BASH, script);
            scriptExecutor.execute(true, args);
        }

        private void terminate() {
            logger.info("Stopping - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This a `Singleton` and the which runs a shell script until it is stopped. This class can be called from anywhere, so I need to stop the thread, if there is any currently executing the shell script, before creating a new `Thread`.

For testing purpose I have executed the `run()` method of this class when the context is initialized and called the `stop()` at the time of destroy.

I have redeploy the war file after removing code `run()`, I was expecting that the `stop()` will terminate the `task`, but it didn't.

I also have tried a different implementation of the `run()` and `stop()`:

```
public void run(String[] frequency) {
    stop();

    task = new Task(frequency);
    Thread thread = RpiThreadFactory.INSTANCE.newThread(task);
    tasks.add(ImmutablePair.of(thread, task));
    thread.start();
}

public void stop() {
    for(ImmutablePair<Thread, Task> pair : tasks) {
        try {
            pair.right.terminate();
            pair.left.join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }           
    }
}
```

Here the `tasks` is `private ArrayList<ImmutablePair<Thread, Task>> tasks = new ArrayList<ImmutablePair<Thread,Task>>();`. The `ImmutablePair` belongs to commons-lang3. But I received `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` on the iteration of the enhanced for loop. The cause I don't know.

### Update

When the server get shutdown the `stop()` is working as expected. I am using Jetty.

### Update

`RpiThreadFactory`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.edfx.rpi.app.utils.logger.RpiLogger;

public enum RpiThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    INSTANCE;

    private final AtomicInteger poolNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final Logger logger = RpiLogger.getLogger(getClass());
    private final ThreadGroup threadGroup;
    private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
    private final String namePrefix;

    private RpiThreadFactory() {
        SecurityManager securityManager = System.getSecurityManager();
        threadGroup = (securityManager != null) ? securityManager.getThreadGroup() : Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
        namePrefix = "RpiPool-" + poolNumber.getAndIncrement() + "-Thread-";

    }

    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadGroup, runnable, namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(), 0);
        thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable cause) {
                logger.error(cause.getMessage(), cause);
            }
        });

        return thread;
    }
}
```

`ScriptExecutor`:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.edfx.rpi.app.utils.logger.RpiLogger;

public class ScriptExecutor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = RpiLogger.getLogger(ScriptExecutor.class);
    public static final String BASH = "/bin/bash";

    private Script script;
    private Process process;
    private String output;
    private int exitValue;

    public ScriptExecutor(Script script) {
        this.script = script;

    }

    public void execute(boolean destroyProcess, String... args) throws ScriptNotExistException {                
        if(!script.exists()) {
            throw new ScriptNotExistException(script.getScriptName() + " does not exists.");
        }

        try {
            List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

            commands.add(BASH);
            commands.add(script.getAbsoultePath());

            if(Objects.nonNull(args)) {
                commands.addAll(Arrays.asList(args));
            }

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Executing script: ");
            builder.append(script.getScriptName());

            if(Objects.nonNull(args) && args.length > 0) {
                builder.append(" with parameters: ");
                builder.append(StringUtils.join(args, " "));
            }

            LOGGER.info(builder.toString());

            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands.toArray(new String[commands.size()]));
            process = processBuilder.start();

            StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String line = StringUtils.EMPTY;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                outputBuilder.append(line);
                outputBuilder.append("\n");
            }

            process.waitFor();

            exitValue = process.exitValue();
            LOGGER.info("Process for: " + script.getScriptName() + " is executed. Exit value: " + exitValue);

            if(destroyProcess) {
                destroyProcess();
            }

            output = outputBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            throw new ScriptExecutionException(cause);
        }       
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public int getExitValue() {
        return exitValue;
    }

    public void destroyProcess() {
        if(Objects.nonNull(process)) {
            LOGGER.info("Process for: " + script.getScriptName() + " is destroyed.");
            process.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

### Purpose

This is a web application running in Jetty web container. The server is installed in an embedded hardware java enabled. How this hardware has a LED attached to it. The application accepts external request, which can be REST and start-stops the LED. So the LED can start blinking for any request; but it serves only one request at a time.

This is why I have the `stop` which stops previously running process, if there is any. The `stop` works for normal condition.

But I saw that while the LED is blinking and I did a deployment without stopping the server the running thread doesn't stops. If I stop the server and did the deployment and the start again, the running thread kills at this time.

The thread loops in the `while` and executes a `Process` to the native. This `Process` is an one time job, so this `Process` is not making the thread to get killed.

To reproduce the issue what I did I created the thread when the context is initialized and tried to kill it when it is destroyed. Now if I write something in the `contextDestroyed` I can see them get executed.

I don't understand why stopping the server kills the thread not when I redeploy.

Comment: I added an answer below, however this code brings up a couple of more questions.
-You are using your own thread factory, why and how does that code look like?
- The second example shows you using an ImmutablePair. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java why you shouldnt do this.

Comment: Could you add println all over the place? That should help you find out what's happening.

Comment: Obviously, killing the server will kill the thread. I would suggest you add some logging to see whats going on. Where is it hanging? Might it be stuck at `process.waitFor();` because there's no more input?

Comment: When you redeploy is terminate called in some place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call process.destroy() on instance of Process returned by processBuilder.start(). Actually what you do when calling BlinkLedTask.terminate() is just setting some flag. You should at this point call process.destroy().

Below I present an example how you can rewrite this.It does not involve your class ScriptExecutor (of course you can move your logic there and return instance of process to BlinkLedTask when calling blinkLed()).

The main difference here is that I'm keeping the reference to instance of Process in field blinkLedProcess and when terminate() is called I'm directly calling process.destroy() to destroy the process.

You wrote that "When the server get shutdown the stop() is working as expected. I am using Jetty." Yes indeed. This is because by calling `processBuilder.start();` you create subprocess of your main jetty process. When you kill jetty all its subproceses are also killed. If you don't kill jetty you need to manually kill the subprocess by calling destroy() method.

It should be something like:

```
public enum BlinkLedTask {
(...)

    private Process resetLedProcess;
    private Process blinkLedProcess;

(...)
   private void blinkLed() throws Exception {
      String[] args = new String[] { frequency[0], frequency[1], frequency[2] };

      List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

      //commands.add(BASH);
      commands.add(script.getAbsoultePath());

      if (Objects.nonNull(args)) {
        commands.addAll(Arrays.asList(args));
      }

      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Executing script: ");
      builder.append(script.getAbsoultePath());

      if (Objects.nonNull(args) && (args.length > 0)) {
        builder.append(" with parameters: ");
        builder.append(StringUtils.join(args, " "));
      }


      ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands.toArray(new String[commands.size()]));

      blinkLedProcess = processBuilder.start();

      StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      InputStream inputStream = blinkLedProcess.getInputStream();
      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

      String line = StringUtils.EMPTY;

      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        outputBuilder.append(line);
        outputBuilder.append("\n");
      }


      blinkLedProcess.waitFor();

      int exitValue = blinkLedProcess.exitValue();
      System.out.println(
        "Process for: " + Script.BLINK_LED.getAbsoultePath() + " is executed. Exit value: " + exitValue);


    }

(...)

   private void terminate() {
      System.out.println("Stopping - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      running = false;
      if (resetLedProcess != null) {
        resetLedProcess.destroy();
        System.out.println("Destroyed reset process");
      }
      if (blinkLedProcess != null) {
        blinkLedProcess.destroy();
        System.out.println("Destroyed blink process");
      }
    }
(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `awaitTermination` to wait after calling `shutdownNow`.

`shutdownNow` will interrupt your thread. Are you sure `ScriptExecutor`does not surpress interrupts?

This might actually be the cause of this.

Also doing this with `SchedulerService` seems redundant since you are only using one thread.

You could start a new thread which you set to a daemon thread (See [What is Daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java)) and it will close automatically when your program exits.

Comment: Hello @jontro, I have updated my question with the `RpiThreadFactory` and `ScriptExecutor` class.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? If its a single thread that runs during the lifetime of your web app then I would just write your own context listener with a thread like this...

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  Thread myThread;
  Task myTask;

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    myTask = new Task();
    myThread = new Thread(myTask);
    myThread.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    myTask.terminate();
    myThread.interrupt();
    myThread.join();
  }
}
```

I'm wondering exactly what it is you want to achieve. Do you only want a single thread running a series of scripts? Or are you hoping, at some point in the future, to have a multi-threaded application?

Any reason for the servlet context? Could you just run this is a straight forward java application?