# Permanent change of a variable in static method

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, static

Let's say I have a public class with static methods, one of them for example:

```
 public static void test(boolean b){
   b = !b;
 }
```

Let's say this class name is Test. From another class, where I have a variable boolean a = false, I call

```
 Test.test(a);
```

How can I make it change a permanently, and not just change it in that static methods scope?

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this as it is likely there is a better way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: I know how to go around it, I just didn't know if this is possible so I felt like asking :)

Comment: Then the answer is don't do that, do something else.  Changing code on the fly is not a simple process.  You should think about changing fields.

Comment: Remember, functions don't receive the variables you pass into them; they receive the values of those variables. They can change the value they stored, but they can't change the variable. See 'Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are looking for a *Mutable* `Boolean`, the simplest of which is an [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

```
private void changeIt(AtomicBoolean b) {
    b.set(!b.get());
}

public void test() {
    AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    changeIt(b);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to make the change permanent is to let the method have a return value and assign it to the variable :

```
public static boolean test(boolean b){
   return !b;
}

a = Test.test(a);
```

Comment: You sure it's the only way? How could I change two variables at once?

Comment: @Greyshack: You don't. If you need multiple variables to change, you should almost certainly encapsulate the combination of those variables in a class.

Comment: @Greyshack Changing two variables at once is not possible. If the variable is a reference to a mutable object, you can change the properties of the object, but you can't change the reference itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static field:

```
public static boolean flag;

public static void test(boolean b){
    flag = !b;
}
```

Then:

```
boolean a = true;
Test.test(a);

System.out.println( Test.flag); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `Test` class you can define the boolean variable as **static**

```
public static boolean a;
```

and outside the class change or access it using `Test.a=false;` or `a=Test.a`

and if you need to use methods you can hide the static method with inheritance:

```
public class HideStatic {     
public static void main(String...args){  
    BaseA base = new ChildB();  
    base.someMethod();        
}  
}  

class BaseA {         
    public static void someMethod(){  
        System.out.println("Parent method");  
    }  
}  

class ChildB extends BaseA{  
    public void someMethod(){  
        System.out.println("Child method");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Ok but that way I have the variable in the class with static methods, and what if I want to have different variables in different classes and use that method?

Comment: so what about hiding them using a new class which inherits the static holder class? (I edited the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an instance to method and use setters to change more variables at once.

```
public static void updateData(MyClass instance) {
    instance.setX(1);
    instance.setY(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for [call by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). You can get this in Java by using arrays:

```
public static void test(boolean[] b){
b[0] = !b[0];
}

boolean[] param = new boolean[] {a};
test(param);
a=param[0];
//a changed
```

This works, but it is ugly. If you need to return more than one value, have a look at [the Pair or Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java/156685#156685) structures.

Comment: Ok, that would make sense, in c,c++ arrays are also pointers to the first element. Good to know :)