# Check whether a tuple key exists in dictionary in java

Tags: java, dictionary, tuples

I've created a java dictionary using java.util.Hashtable with 2-tuple of strings as it's keys and int as values.

```
class pair<e,f>{
  public e one;
  public f two;
}
```

I used to above class to initialize a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<pair<String, String>, Integer> dict = new Hashtable();
```

Now I'm unable to check whether a key exists in dict, I mean I am unable to pass pair of strings as argument to dict.containsKey() method.

Comment: Class names start with a capital letter like Pair.

Comment: I don't think that matters! I mean for the sake of functionality.

Comment: Yes, it does not matter for functionality, but for understanding and maintanibility of your code.

Comment: I know it, but here functionality is all that matters. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public class Pair<E, F> {
    private final E e;
    private final F f;
    public Pair(E e, F f) {
        this.e = e;
        this.f = f;
    }

    public E getE() {
        return e;
    }
    public F getF() {
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Pair<E,F> other = (Pair<E,F>) obj;
        if (!this.e.equals(other.getE())) {
           return false;
        }
        if (!this.f.equals(other.getF())) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        hash = 53 * e.hashCode() + f.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

I've assumed that `e` and `f` is not `null`. If it can be `null` then you must check whether `e == null` before the `if(e.equals(other.getE())` to prevent a NPE.

**Further notes:**

- You should in almost all cases set members of a class to `private`
  (except `static` members).
- [Proper Java convention is to have class names in `CapitalizedWords`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).
- [Generic type parameters should be a single upper-case character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` for stuff you want to use as Hashtable keys. If you don't do that, the default mechanism is used, and that will use object identity, not object equality (meaning two tuples are not considered equal even if they contain "equal" entries).

And the key fields should really be immutable, otherwise it can also break things.

Comment: Could you give me a code snippet, just for basic idea what you are trying to say?

Comment: There are a few here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java