# WebSocket Slow - Java and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, bukkit

I am dealing with encoding of a minecraft plugin.
But now I have the following problem, my websocket server respond very very slow.

Here is my WebSocketClass (For the plugin)

// socket server class

```
package me.mickerd.pcoc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ClientHandshake;
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;

public class WebsocketServer extends WebSocketServer {
public static WebsocketServer s;

public WebsocketServer(int port) throws UnknownHostException {
    super(new InetSocketAddress(port));
}

public WebsocketServer(InetSocketAddress address) {
    super(address);
}

@Override
public void onOpen(WebSocket conn, ClientHandshake handshake) {
    WebsocketSessionManager.getSessionManager().openSession(conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    Bukkit.getLogger().info(conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostName() + " has connected to the Websocket server!");
}

@Override
public void onClose(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
    WebsocketSessionManager.getSessionManager().endSession(conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    Bukkit.getLogger().info(conn + " has disconnected form the Websocket server");
}

@Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
    Bukkit.getLogger().info("Recieve Websocket packet - " + conn + ":" + message);
    if (message.split(":")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
        WebsocketSessionManager.getSessionManager().addSessionUsername(conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress(), message.split(":")[1]);
    }
}

public static void runServer() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    WebSocketImpl.DEBUG = true;
    int port = 8887;
    s = new WebsocketServer(port);
    s.start();
    Bukkit.getLogger().info("Websocket server started on port: " + s.getPort());
}

@Override
public void onError(WebSocket conn, Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    if (conn != null) {
        // some errors like port binding failed may not be assignable to a specific websocket
    }
}

public void sendToAll(String data) {
    Collection<WebSocket> con = connections();
    synchronized (con) {
        for (WebSocket c : con) {
            c.send(data);
        }
    }
}

public void sendData(WebsocketSession session, String data) {
    Collection<WebSocket> con = connections();
    synchronized (con) {
        for (WebSocket c : con) {
            if (c.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(session.getHost())) {
                Bukkit.getLogger().info("Send data packet: " + data);
                c.send(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and this is my receiver in Javascript:

```
var sound = null;
var name = window.location
document.session.name.value = name

var text = document.session.name.value

var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.hostname + ":8887/");

ws.onopen = function () {
        ws.send("name:" + delineate(text));
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Welcome on the music server. Please hold this window open!";

};

ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Then bind the event to the callback function.
    // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    // Fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}
if(evt.data == "stop"){
  sound.fadeOut(0, 3700);
} else {
sound = new Howl({
  urls: ['music/' + evt.data + '.ogg']
}).play();
console.log("playing music");
};
}

ws.onclose = function () {
    alert("Closed!");
};

ws.onerror = function (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err);
};

function delineate(str) {
    theleft = str.indexOf("=") + 1;
    theright = str.lastIndexOf("&");
    return (str.substring(theleft, theright));
}
```

The reacts very slow, but other things on the server are incredible fast!

Can someone help?

Comment: What is your internet connection speed?

Comment: Have a look with Wireshark to see what part of the communication is slow and report back.

Answer (score 2):

The websocket library you are using sends data blocking, this means that a call to `c.send(` will block until the frame is send.

There are different ways to solve this, for example:

### Using a separate async thread for every message:

```
public void sendToAll(String data) {
    // Ferrybig - added bukkit async task
    Bukkit.getSchedular().runTaskAsynchronously(plugin, new Runnable(){
    @Override public void run(){
        Collection<WebSocket> con = connections();
        synchronized (con) {
            for (WebSocket c : con) {
                c.send(data);
            }
        }
    // Ferrybig - added bukkit async task
    }});
}
```

While this solves you problem quickly, it isn't a clean solution since a large amount of send messages means that there are a large number of threads created for the purpose of message sending, ie don't send to often, or see next solution:

### Using a dedicated thread for the message sending:

Using a dedicated thread for the sending of messages is the better solution, but it comes with its large code.

For this solution, we need to do the following:

- **Use a variable to store the messages that need to be send to every client**

  ```
  private final BlockingQueue<Pair<WebSocket,String>> messageQueue
                = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
  ```

  We use a Blocking queue that holds Pair objects containing the web socket and the message to be send. While we also could used the Map.Entry classes  from Map, I choose to use a Pair since we can later change the code a little to make it automatically resort message based on priority. The Pair class I used for this answer can be found at [What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677248/1542723).
- **Using a dedicated thread to send the messages**

  We have list of incoming messages now, we now to process the messages as they come in. This can be done by making a task that blocks on [`messageQueue.take()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()). The following is a quick implementation of this:

  ```
  public class MessageProcessor extends BukkitRunnable {

      private BlockingQueue<Pair<WebSocket,String>> messageQueue;

      public MessageProcessor (BlockingQueue<Pair<WebSocket,String>> messageQueue) {
          this.messageQueue = messageQueue;
      }

      @Override 
      public void run() {
          try {
              Pair<WebSocket,String> next;
              while(true) {
                  next = messageQueue.take();
                  if(next.getFirst() == null) {
                      // Special condition, will be explained later
                      return; // Quit run method
                  }
                  // System.out.println("Send message to " + next.getFirst()); // DEBUG
                  next.getFirst().send(next.getSecond());
              }
          } catch(InterruptedException e) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              // Someone wanted to quit our thread, so we are quiting
          } finally {
              messageQueue.clear();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  The above class has 2 special conditions, `next.getFirst() == null` and `catch(InterruptedException e)`, these will be used when we disable the plugin to quit the task.

  - **Start our dedicated task when bukkit is started**

  We need to start our task when bukkit and our Websocket server is started, so it can start processing messages and sending data. This is easy to do in our `onEnable()` with the following code:

  new MessageProcessor (messageQueue).runTaskAsynchronously(this);

  - **Stopping the dedicated task**

  We need to make sure the dedicated task is stopped when our plugin is disabled to prevent bukkit from spamming the error "`This plugin is not properly shutting down its async tasks when it is being reloaded.`". This is really easy to do since we have made a special condition for this above.

  To do this, we place the following code in our `onDisable()`:

  [`messageQueue.add(new Pair<>(null,null));`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#add(E))

  - **Rewriting our methods to use the messageQueue**

  Our last step in the process is to rewrite the `sendToAll` method to use our queue. This is really easy to do any only requires us to replace 1 line.

  ```
  public void sendToAll(String data) {
      Collection<WebSocket> con = connections();
      synchronized (con) {
          for (WebSocket c : con) {
              messageQueue.add(new Pair<>(c,data)); // Ferrybig: Use messageQueue
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  The same small modification can also be done for `sendData` method, but isn't done by me as an exercise for the reader.

### Sidenotes

A `BlockingQueue` is designed with concurrent actions in mind, and doesn't require external synchronization.

You may choose to use [`BlockingQueue.offer()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer(E)) instead of `BlockingQueue.add()` because the fact the latter throws an exception when the list is full, but the first returns false.

The default size for a `LinkedBlockingDeque` is [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) and can be changed with its [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html#LinkedBlockingDeque(int)).