# How to get the top-k closest elements in a Java TreeSet?

Tags: java, treeset

Supposing I have this `TreeSet<Integer>`:

```
1 3 4 6 8 9 10
```

And I want the top-`k` "closest" elements to an input number `x`.

For example, with `k=3` and `x=5` I want to get:

`4 6 3`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "Is there any way to do this?" Yes. Write a method to do so. If you mean "Is there a method in TreeSet that does this?", the answer is no.

Comment: Also, if you plan to implement this yourself (which you probably will have to), you'll need to define certain cases. What happens if `k` is greater than the size of the set? What happens if `x` is not in the set? What happens if two elements are tied for closest?

Answer (score 4):

It seems what you need to do is to get a [headSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#headSet(E)) with all elements smaller than the target element and a [tailSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet(E)) for the bigger elements. Now the algorithm will be somewhat similar to merge phase of merge sort.

- Take a [descendingIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#descendingIterator()) of the headSet and an [iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#iterator()) over the tail set. Call these `c_desc`, and `c_asc`
- Check which of the two elements is closer to the target value `x`. Take this value and advance the iterator
- Take care for when one of the iterators is at the end of the corresponding set view
- Continue doing that until you have taken `k` elements

Comment: Don't do work for OP. How will OP learn if you do all the lifting for them?

Comment: I have not done any work for the OP, only pointed to the appropriate functions. It is still up to OP to turn this into actual implementation by researching the relevant documentation that I have pointed to.

Comment: I suppose. IMHO what you've given is essentially pseudo-code, which is relatively easy to turn into actual code.

Comment: @lucasvw Giving pointers is totally accepted. Heck, you even give some in your second comment of the question! "Do as I say, not as I do"?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable amount of detail for a homework question. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822): *"You can use pseudo-code first...".*

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire There's a big difference between pointing out potential problems (my second comment), and providing a lot of the work that needs to be done (this answer).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I would also point out that OP did practically nothing to attempt to solve this first, which is a guideline to asking homework questions in the link provided by Andy Thomas

Comment: So what? Act appropriately and flag the question and don't berate answerers.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I don't believe I've berated anyone, but I will gladly apologize if I have. I merely expressed my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

By "closest to x" I assume you mean the lowest values of `abs(n - x)`.

That is, for x=5, k=3:

```
1,3,4,6,8,9,10   -> 3,4,6
3,4,5,10,11,12   -> 3,4,5
0,1,2,5,6,7,8    -> 5,6,7
```

If that's the case, I would:

- map each `Integer` to a `Pair<Integer,Integer>`

  - `n -> new Pair(n, abs(n - x))` so one value is `n`, the other is its distance from `x`.
  - (write your own `Pair`, (ab)use `Map.Entry`, (ab)use `Integer[2]` or find one in a library)
- sort the list of `Pair<>` using a comparator that uses the distance
- take the first `k` elements from that sorted list.

Using Java 8 streams:

```
 set.stream()
   .map( n -> new Pair(n, Math.abs(x - n)))
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing( p -> p.right())
   .limit(k)
   .map( p -> p.left())
   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java