# Swapping keys in TreeSet?

Tags: java, hashset, treeset

Suppose I have this class:

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
  public float key;
  public TreeSet<Node> neighbors;

  public Node{
    //fill neighbors somehow
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Node n) {
    if(this.key == n.key)
        return 0;
    else if(this.key > n.key)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
  }

}
```

So this is a classic node of a graph, where each node is connected to a set of nodes (i.e. its neighbors). I'm using `TreeSet` because I often (very often) to know all the neighbors with their key bigger (smaller) than a certain value. Now, let's suppose I have this method:

```
//swap nodes keys
void swapKeys(Node a, Node b){
  float ak = a.key;
  a.key = b.key;
  b.key = ak; 
}
```

Notice that this method changes only the two nodes keys, nothing more.

Do this "break" the structure, or everything will continue to work fine?

If this breaks the structure, what about this simple solution:

```
//swap nodes keys
void swapKeys(Node a, Node b){
  a.remove(b);
  b.remove(a);
  float ak = a.key;
  a.key = b.key;
  b.key = ak; 
  a.add(b);
  b.add(a);
}
```

Comment: This will break the structure. Keys should be immutable. Hashcode cannot change once added as a key.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda Thanks for your answer. What about my solution that I just posted?

Comment: @JonnyHenly edited while you were posting your comment lol

Comment: Why swap the nodes' keys and alter the structure when you could simply swap their values and not alter the structure?

Comment: How many neighbors will a node have? Maybe you can get away with just using a list rather than a set.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I'm afraid I don't understand your comment, what do you mean?

Comment: @arshajii for hubs (nodes at the center of a network with high degree) potentially thousands.

Comment: I was wrong, I'm using `TreeSet` and not `HashSet`

Answer (score 1):

From the [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) documentation :

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface.

Your `Node` class' `Comparable` implementation is not consistent with `equals`. (`compareTo` can return `0` for two `Node` instances wich are not equal).

This in itself makes your `Node` class unfit to be elements of a `TreeSet`.

Even the proposed workaround is not sufficient.

You may be tempted to fix this by implementing `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) to be based upon the value contained in the node. But to no avail, as this would go against a warning on the documention of the general [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface :

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set
>   elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an
>   object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while
>   the object is an element in the set. A special case of this
>   prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself
>   as an element.

So adding equals and hashCode is still not sufficient : your instances must also be immutable.

However the simplest solution, seems to be to forego the `Comparable` interface altogether, to not implement `equals` and `hashCode`, and to simply use a `HashSet` instead of a `TreeSet`. In that case you can change the contents of your nodes without consequences to the proper functioning of the set of neighbours.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Are you telling me that I have to implement `equals` too?

Comment: `HashSet` unfortunately is not an option since I frequently use `tailSet` and `headSet` to compute topK as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525091/how-to-get-the-top-k-closest-elements-in-a-java-treeset)

Comment: You'll have to go with immutable Nodes then. This will entail replacing them in your graph, instead of changing their contents.
Or use `HashSet` regardless, and create a `TreeSet` with a `Comparator`, locally in the algorithm to find the k nearest nodes.