# Java Generics: Useing multiple generic types in one collection type

Tags: java, generics, collections

I would like to use two generic types as a key for a hash map. Effectively:

```
Map<CollectionType<Integer, Integer>, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I am trying to find if this is possible, and if so which collection type I could use. The right type needs to be able to accept duplicate values. i.e. <1, 0>, <1, 1>, <2, 0> could all be used as a key in the map

for additional background the key in the map will be coordinates on a hex grid, and the value is what is currently stored at that location.

Comment: *The right type needs to be able to accept duplicate values.* What do you mean? Maps don't allow duplicate keys.

Comment: maybe use a pair: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java ?

Comment: Or an Entry. Or make your type.

Comment: can `<1, 0>` repeat multiple times as key in your case?

Comment: @secretsuperstar no the combination of integers will always be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Pair<Integer, Integer>`, provided by many libraries like in `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair` or in jdk as `javafx.util.Pair`.

`equals()` and `hashcode()` are overridden, so it can work as a key in the Map.

```
Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
```